# How to gather markers into on on zoom out with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I have a Google Maps view on my web-app.

I have custom markers with custom infoviews on it.

On zoom-out, instead of having the map crowded with tons of markers, I would like to gather them together with a number on it.

- How can I do this?

I tried searching for it but I am not sure what to even look for as I am very new to this.

Any help and redirection is very much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you want the [markerclusterer](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html).  [Post describing it](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html)

Comment: @geocodezip, please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: And to eejits who decided to "close" because it's "too broad", there you go. a single API call. How can you classify as too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [markerclusterer](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html). [Post describing it](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html)